An equivalent form for the trace-class norm
Let $H$ be Hilbert space, 
Let $\mathscr{B}(H)$,$\mathscr{B}_0(H)$, $\mathscr{B}_1(H)$ be , respectivetly ,the bounded, compact and trace-class operator space, 
Let define $\| A\|_1 = tr(|A|)$,
I would prove that:
$\| A\|_1 = sup\{ |tr(BA)|\ : B \in   \mathscr{B}_0(H) \, s.t. \|B\| \leq 1 \}$
I think that I had prove the $\geq$, but i'm stuck for the other inequality

Let the polar decomposition of $A$ be $A = U|A|$. Fix a sequence (net, if the Hilbert space is not separable) of finite rank projections $P_n$ which increases to $1$. Then $B_n = P_nU^\ast$ are compact and have norm at most $1$. We have,
$$\|A\|_1 = \text{Tr}(|A|) = |\text{Tr}(U^\ast A)| = \lim_n |\text{Tr}(B_nA)|$$
which establishes the $\leq$ inequality.
